# ASP.NET CORE Error when trying to add a List of Objects to an Object with a list in it

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

I have a ASP.Net Core project that I'm working on. So I have a Linq call that gets the information from the database and sends it back to the Controller, no problem there. When I send this data to the View I get an error

> The model item passed into the ViewDataDictionary is of type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[PhotoUploader.Models.UnitPictures]', but this ViewDataDictionary instance requires a model item of type 'PhotoUploader.Models.FileViewModel'.

Now I know why this is, Its because the model types don't match from the controller to the View. My question is, how do I assign the `UnitPictures` to the `FileViewModel` list I've created inside of it.

Model

```
public class UnitPictures
{
    public long ImageId { get; set; }
    public string FileName { get; set; }
    public string FileLocation { get; set; }
    public int SortOrder { get; set; }
}
```

View Model

```
public class FileViewModel 
{
    public FileViewModel()
    {
        UnitPicturesList = new List<UnitPictures>();
    }
    //Other Fields here
    public List<UnitPictures> UnitPicturesList { get; set; }
}
```

Method Call return data of type UnitPictures

```
    private List<UnitPictures> GetImages(long Id)
    {
        var images = (from a in _db.Images
                      join b in _db.AutoImage 
                        on  a.ImageId equals b.ImageId
                      where b.Id == Id
                      select new UnitPictures
                      {
                         FileLocation = "",
                         FileName = a.FileName,
                         SortOrder = 0, 
                         ImageId = a.ImageId

                      }).ToList();

        return images;
    }
```

Controller

```
    public IActionResult UnitImages(long Id, long unitId)
    {           
        var images = GetImages(Id);           

                  
        return View(images);
    }
```

View

```
 @model FileViewModel

 <div class="row">
  <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-12 mb-4 mb-lg-0">

 @for (var i = 0; i < Model.UnitPicturesList.Count; i++)
 {
    <img
      src="https://mdbcdn.b-cdn.net/img/Photos/Horizontal/Nature/4-col/img%20(73).webp"
      class="w-100 shadow-1-strong rounded mb-4"
      alt="Boat on Calm Water"
    />
 }
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You create an instance of the view model, populate the relevant members and return that to the view.

```
public IActionResult UnitImages(long Id, long unitId)  
    var images = GetImages(Id);           
    FileViewModel model = new FileViewModel() {
        UnitPicturesList = images
    };                   
    return View(model);
}
```

The will allow the view to now properly bind to the matching members in the ViewDataDictionary

Answer (score 2):

If your viewmodel is of type `FileViewModel`, that's what you need to pass to `View`:

```
public IActionResult UnitImages(long Id, long unitId)
{           
    FileViewModel viewModel = new(){ UnitPicturesList = GetImages(Id) };           
              
    return View(viewModel);
}
```

Since you have a mutable `UnitPicturesList` property, just assigning it directly like this will work.

Comment: what is it called when you do it like this?  `= new(){ UnitPicturesList = GetImages(Id) }`

Comment: @whisk that's a combination of the ["targed-typed new" functionality from C# 9](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/proposals/csharp-9.0/target-typed-new) in conjunction with standard "object initializers".

Answer (score 1):

You need to create an instance of **FileViewModel** and then assign the property **UnitPictureList** to the result of **GetImages**. Finally you return the View passing the instance of FileViewModel

```
public IActionResult UnitImages(long Id, long unitId)
{           
    var fileModel = new FileViewModel();
    fileModel.UnitPicturesList = GetImages(Id);           
    return View(fileModel);
}
```

Can be shortened even more with

```
var fileModel = new FileViewModel{UnitPicturesList=GetImages(Id)};
```

Comment: This is clean and short!

Comment: Can be shortened even more with _var fileModel = new FileViewModel{UnitPicturesList=GetImages(Id)};_